# How to fix Visual Studio C# Project Properties not showing?

Tags: c#

When I try to open ANY c#(also new project created at the moment), I can't view its properties.
I got this error(translated):

An error occurred while trying to load project properties window.
Close the window and retry.
The value cannot be null.
Parameter name: val

I tried to restore vs, also tried this method: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/3fb200e0-14cf-4684-bb7f-71b7808a1f83/project-not-loading-properly?forum=visualstudiogeneral

But none of those worked..

Comment: Try after opening a new project to do a File : SaveAll to a folder you have full read/write permission.  Then try looking at properties.

Comment: What version of visual studio are you using?  Doing a search for your error I came up with some people not having '.NET desktop development component' installed and they had to modify their installation to add it.  Have you added any extensions?  There's also a mention of a 'Ghostdoc' extension causing issues.  If neither of these fix it you may need to uninstall visual studio completely and reinstall with default settings to see if it works, then make any changes you want by modifying the install and see if it breaks.

Comment: Bizarrely after reading your post, something like this just happened to me. The window blanked out and had an error message (after renaming a class using Resharper). I closed and repoened the new file with no problem -- seems VS "got lost". Given my experience and Jason's post, this suggests to me that you should try to load VS without extensions to see if one of them is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by UPDATING (not restoring/repairing) Visual Studio to last build.
That doesn't make any sense by the way: like 2 months ago this version worked too(incl. project properties page).
I guess when Microsoft releases updates it forces you somehow to update its softwares.

Answer (score 12):

Solved for me by removing .vs folder.